# How to check if objects in class are serializable in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization

What am I trying to do is as follows:

```
[serializable]
public class A
{

    B b = new B();
}

public class B
{
    public b()
    {}
}

public class SerilizableCheker()
{
    A a = new A();
    if( a.IsSerializable)    // true;
    {

    }
}
```

As B's object, in class A, is not serializable that is why it will throw an exception, when I go for serialization. Is there any method to find that objects in Class A are also serializable and if they arre not the throw an exception.

Reflection could be an option which is coming in mind but there could be an hierarchy of such aggregation of object. So is there any way to find it without manually fetching each contamination and then check for serialization ?

This Question is totally different as question is about replacement of IsSerializable attribute.

Comment: To try to serialize graph is much easier, than inspecting this graph for serialization ability. Why do you need this? I mean, why exception is not an option for you?

Comment: Create your own extension method is the only approach for you :P

Comment: Reason is simple. I don't want my code to break at run time.